# Isomorphism of maximal subgroups fix the Frattini?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, maximal-subgroup, frattini-subgroup

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $M$ and $N$ be two maximal subgroups of $G$. If $f: M \to N$ is an isomorphism, is it true that $f(\Phi(G)) \subseteq \Phi(G)$, where $\Phi(G)$ denotes the Frattini subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order 8, and $M = N$ a Klein four-subgroup.  The Frattini subgroup of $G$ is the order-2 subgroup generated by a 180-degree rotation, and this is not fixed by all automorphisms of $M$.